# Specflow not finding external bindings

Tags: c#, binding, specflow

I have two assemblies with bindings that I need to incorporate into a new assembly.

I've edited my stepBindings to reference both of the assemblies that I need:

```
<stepAssemblies>
    <stepAssembly assembly="DseSoapApiTests" />
    <stepAssembly assembly="DseRestApiTests" />
</stepAssemblies>
```

The DseRestApiTests bindings load. I've verified that both names match the assembly names in the .csproj's.

Does anyone have any tips on troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: if you remove the reference to the `DseRestApiTests` do the others load then? Is the assembly `DseSoapApiTests` referenced by the test project and copied to the output folder? Those are the first things I would check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bindings were silently failing to load due to overlapping names, despite being in different namespaces. I.e. in the DseSoapApiTests and DseRestApiTests there was a GlobalBaseProperties.cs file. Weirdly enough, both bindings would load a fraction of the time, but Specflow was definitely not happy.